# Why dynamic content changes across all browsers?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, dynamic-data

I have a node.js application having basic authentication and I have added socket.io for real time messaging.I login across three browsers using three different credentials.Example

1. xyz@xyz.com
2. abc@abc.com
3. 123@123.com

After each user logs in, I add them to the list of currently logged in users removing the current user.

1. Such that for 3rd (***123@123.com***) user only **xyz@xyz.com** & **abc@abc.com** are shown online.
2. Such that for 2nd (***abc@abc.com***) user only **xyz@xyz.com** & **123@123.com** are shown online.

***The logic works properly and I console logged from the server side.***

> But the problem is the online users displayed in the website is **overwritten across all browsers** by the lastly logged in user.

If **123@123.com** has logged in lastly.The list of online users across all browsers is overwritten to **xyz@xyz.com , abc@abc.com** and vice versa.

> **Result:**
>
> 1. So for 3rd user (123@123.com) **xyz@xyz.com & abc@abc.com** are shown online.
> 2. So for 2nd user (abc@abc.com) **xyz@xyz.com & abc@abc.com** are shown online.
> 3. So for 1st user (xyz@xyz.com) **xyz@xyz.com & abc@abc.com** are shown online.

Code for the client side to update the online users.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    // get the current user email
    var email = $("#email").text();
    socket.emit('user', email);

    // list of online users returned from server
    socket.on('users_connected',function (users) {
        updateUsers(users);
    });


    function updateUsers(users){
        var list = [];
        for(var i =0; i<users.length; i++){
            var user = "<a href='#'>"+users[i]+"</a>";
            list.push(user);
            $( "#users" ).html(list);
        }
    }
});
```

Answers needed for:

1. **Why does the content change across browsers.Is the web app not a new instance of the app in each browser ?**
2. **How do I fix this ?**

Comment: I'm new to node.js please help me out ?

Comment: Can you list the server side code? I think your problem is when you are updating the users you send the result to all connected socket connections instead of just one of the socket connections, thus you change every users login info instead of just one user.